# How can I handle the one UITapGesturerecognizer for morethan one uiimageviews

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an application. In which I am using the seventy `UIImageViews`. For all `UIImageViews` I am using single `UITapgestureRecognizer`. But only its working for last `UIImageView`.

So please tell me how can I use the single `UITapGgestureRecognizer` for that all `UIImageViews`.My code looks like

```
radiotap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(radiochanged:)];
radiotap.delegate=self;

a=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, male.frame.origin.y, ima.size.width, ima.size.height)];
[a setImage:ima];
a.tag=0;
a.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[a addGestureRecognizer:radiotap];
[scroll addSubview:a];


 b=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, female.frame.origin.y, ima.size.width, ima.size.height)];
[a setImage:ima];
b.tag=1;
b.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[b addGestureRecognizer:radiotap];
[scroll addSubview:b];
```

Like this I added the 70 UIImageViews.

Comment: can you show code how you are doing this?

Comment: Where you are declaring UITapGgestureRecognizer?is it global or local?

Comment: Globally declared the UITapGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the tap gesture recognisers to the container of the image views
2. Disable userinteraction on all your image views

This way the touch is passed beneath to the container holding the image views.

Hey i got your issue now.

Create new gesture recognizers for each of the image views. The problem is you have created just a single instance of a gesture recognizer.

I hope you got the bug there and will edit your code appropriately. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: But if i do like that then that gesture method will be fired when i click on that container.

Comment: Is that not what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign one `UITapGestureRecognizer` to one `UIView`. One idea is to subclass `UIIimageView` and add a `UITapgestureRecognizer` as a property. And alloc/init for every `UIImageView` a new `UITapGestureRecognizer` in a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

when you add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a view in reality you are doing this:

you are setting a property of the UITapGestureRecognizer that contain the view linked to:
meaning that each UITapGestureRecognizer has ONLY a uiview associated to it.

that's why you can see it ONLY in the last one you setted.

to do what you want to so you need to create/allocate/init a UITapGestureRecognizer for each view...